# Is it worth using Flexbox if I have to support IE9?

Tags: css, flexbox, modernizr

I am working on a new project which involves building a chat window. Normally, I would have no hesitation in using Flexbox for this project, *however*, a requirement of this project is that I support IE9.

I know that using tools like Modernizr can provide a fallback, but if I need to support this anyways is there much advantage of using this method?

Comment: You like the speed of a car, and want the same performance on your horse and buggy. Good luck... You can't get CSS3 technology to work on old browsers, such as IE9. You can try but you're looking at a great deal of complexity with no guarantee of success. Here's a bit more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: Just to add to @Michael_B, you can always check compatibility by going to [can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) and checking what browser has support for it.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not worth it. You'll wind up doing everything twice to get the fallback support, so spend your effort doing it once, fully compatible with the oldest browser you need to support.